# Why can't I remove the Shipping address from this IPP QBO v3 API Customer object

Tags: rest, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm using the Intuit Partner Platform v3 QBO API to try to update [a Customer object](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/customer). The sole objective for the purpose of this post is to remove the shipping address.

Here's the original object, queried before the change:

```
{
    "domain": "QBO", 
    "FamilyName": "last", 
    "DisplayName": "my display name", 
    "Title": "mr.", 
    "PreferredDeliveryMethod": "Print", 
    "GivenName": "first", 
    "FullyQualifiedName": "my display name", 
    "BillWithParent": false, 
    "Job": false, 
    "BalanceWithJobs": 0, 
    "Taxable": true, 
    "MetaData": {
        "CreateTime": "2014-09-22T18:49:43-07:00", 
        "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-09-22T18:49:44-07:00"
    }, 
    "BillAddr": {
        "City": "city 1", 
        "Country": "USA", 
        "Line1": "billing address line 1\nbilling address line 2", 
        "PostalCode": "98765", 
        "CountrySubDivisionCode": "ST", 
        "Id": "130"
    }, 
    "MiddleName": "mid", 
    "Active": true, 
    "Balance": 0, 
    "SyncToken": "0", 
    "Suffix": "suf", 
    "CompanyName": "my company name", 
    "ShipAddr": {
        "City": "city 2", 
        "Country": "USA", 
        "Line1": "shipping address line 1\nshipping address line 2", 
        "PostalCode": "54321", 
        "CountrySubDivisionCode": "TS", 
        "Id": "131"
    }, 
    "PrintOnCheckName": "my display name", 
    "sparse": false, 
    "Id": "212"
}
```

Here's the request body when I do the update (SyncToken matches, sparse is false...):

```
{
    "domain": "QBO", 
    "DisplayName": "my display name", 
    "Title": "mr.", 
    "PreferredDeliveryMethod": "Print", 
    "GivenName": "first", 
    "FullyQualifiedName": "my display name", 
    "BillWithParent": false, 
    "Job": false, 
    "BalanceWithJobs": 0.0, 
    "Taxable": true, 
    "MetaData": {
        "CreateTime": "2014-09-22T18:49:43-07:00", 
        "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-09-22T18:49:43-07:00"
    }, 
    "sparse": false, 
    "MiddleName": "mid", 
    "Active": true, 
    "Balance": 0.0, 
    "SyncToken": 0, 
    "Suffix": "suf", 
    "CompanyName": "my company name", 
    "FamilyName": "last", 
    "PrintOnCheckName": "my display name", 
    "BillAddr": {
        "CountrySubDivisionCode": "ST", 
        "City": "city 1", 
        "PostalCode": "98765", 
        "Line1": "billing address line 1\nbilling address line 2", 
        "Country": "USA"
    }, 
    "Id": "212"
}
```

And then when I read it again afterwards, it still has the shipping address (though note the SyncToken has incremented, so the API 'got the message':

```
{
    "domain": "QBO", 
    "FamilyName": "last", 
    "DisplayName": "my display name", 
    "Title": "mr.", 
    "PreferredDeliveryMethod": "Print", 
    "GivenName": "first", 
    "FullyQualifiedName": "my display name", 
    "BillWithParent": false, 
    "Job": false, 
    "BalanceWithJobs": 0, 
    "Taxable": true, 
    "MetaData": {
        "CreateTime": "2014-09-22T18:49:43-07:00", 
        "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-09-22T18:51:20-07:00"
    }, 
    "BillAddr": {
        "City": "city 1", 
        "Country": "USA", 
        "Line1": "billing address line 1\nbilling address line 2", 
        "PostalCode": "98765", 
        "CountrySubDivisionCode": "ST", 
        "Id": "130"
    }, 
    "MiddleName": "mid", 
    "Active": true, 
    "Balance": 0, 
    "SyncToken": "1", 
    "Suffix": "suf", 
    "CompanyName": "my company name", 
    "ShipAddr": {
        "City": "city 1", 
        "Country": "USA", 
        "Line1": "billing address line 1\nbilling address line 2", 
        "PostalCode": "98765", 
        "CountrySubDivisionCode": "ST", 
        "Id": "130"
    }, 
    "PrintOnCheckName": "my display name", 
    "sparse": false, 
    "Id": "212"
}
```

I've found that if I just set a SINGLE line of the shipping address (to 'x', for example, then the change goes through, but what I'm trying above (which is what I really want—to DELETE the shipping address), has failed. I don't see it on the [known issues list](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq/qbo_v3_known_issues), but I know that when a friend of mine recently migrated from QuickBooks Desktop to QuickBooks Online, shipping addresses were populated where previously there was just a billing address.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do a read call and then try to update using full payload. Send the metadata info also. Let me know if that works.

Comment: You might also want to check this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038662/update-a-customer-in-qbo-api-3/24044522#24044522 if you are using dotnet sdk.

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm trying it all in the API Explorer. I do a read, I copy and paste the inner object dictionary from the response into the update box (which already has spare = false), delete the ShipAddr dict, and the response still shows the shipping address.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered almost similar issue to this... I had to create a customer on QBO using the same POST api with all the fields except shipping address so that customer created on QBO should not contain any shipping address.
But when I tried that with the request data:

```
{
  "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
    "Address": "jdrew@myemail.com"
  }, 
  "DisplayName": "King's Groceries", 
  "CompanyName": "King Groceries", 
  "BillAddr": {
    "CountrySubDivisionCode": "CA", 
    "City": "Mountain View", 
    "PostalCode": "94042", 
    "Line1": "123 Main Street", 
    "Country": "USA"
  }
}
```

The response I received:

```
{
 "Customer": {
  "Taxable": true,
  "BillAddr": {
   "Id": "202",
   "Line1": "123 Main Street",
   "City": "Mountain View",
   "Country": "USA",
   "CountrySubDivisionCode": "CA",
   "PostalCode": "94042"
  },
  "Job": false,
  "BillWithParent": false,
  "Balance": 0,
  "BalanceWithJobs": 0,
  "CurrencyRef": {
   "value": "USD",
   "name": "United States Dollar"
  },
  "PreferredDeliveryMethod": "Print",
  "IsProject": false,
  "domain": "QBO",
  "sparse": false,
  "Id": "75",
  "SyncToken": "0",
  "MetaData": {
   "CreateTime": "2023-07-12T01:45:04-07:00",
   "LastUpdatedTime": "2023-07-12T01:45:04-07:00"
  },
  "FullyQualifiedName": "King's Groceries",
  "CompanyName": "King Groceries",
  "DisplayName": "King's Groceries",
  "PrintOnCheckName": "King Groceries",
  "Active": true,
  "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
   "Address": "jdrew@myemail.com"
  },
  "DefaultTaxCodeRef": {
   "value": "2"
  }
 },
 "time": "2023-07-12T01:45:04.818-07:00"
}
```

Clearly there is no Shipping Address in the Response but when I analyse the same thing on the QBO UI, I can see the shipping address which was there exactly same as the billing address

[QBO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw4Hj.png)

I thought it could be a possibility that QBO consider Billing Address same as Shipping Address when Shipping Address not provided in the request body.
So I tried passing null or blank string in the Shipping Address parameters:

```
{
  "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
    "Address": "jdrew2@myemail.com"
  }, 
  "DisplayName": "Queen's Groceries", 
  "CompanyName": "Queen Groceries", 
  "BillAddr": {
    "CountrySubDivisionCode": "CA", 
    "City": "Mountain View", 
    "PostalCode": "94044", 
    "Line1": "1234 Main Street", 
    "Country": "USA"
  },
  "ShipAddr": {
    "CountrySubDivisionCode": "", 
    "City": "", 
    "PostalCode": "", 
    "Line1": "", 
    "Country": ""
  }
}
```

But no luck.

So I pondered and implemented a workaround for this that might be help in your case:

```
        //check for shipping address same as billing
        if(stripeSettingRec.Use_Billing_Address_as_Shipping_Address__c){
            customer.ShipAddr = bilAddr;
        }
        else {
            shipAddress.Line1 = '‎ ';//
            customer.ShipAddr = shipAddress;
        }
```

Now here what have I done is... If the customer wants us to keep the Shipping Address same as Billing then our Shipping Address becomes same as Billing.

Else we want to keep Shipping Address Blank, `shipAddress.Line1 = '‎ ';`

We are not passing space in the string, What we are doing is **passing an invisible character U+200e** here in the shipAddress.Line1

It can be copied from the else block above or from this [link](https://www.editpad.org/tool/invisible-character)

This would confuse QBO and create a sense that we are containing something in our shipping address.

I think this would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** Adding working JSON example.

```
{
  "Customer": {
    "Taxable": false,
    "BillAddr": {
      "Id": "9",
      "Line1": "100 Street",
      "City": "Bangalore",
      "Country": "India",
      "CountrySubDivisionCode": "Karnataka",
      "PostalCode": "560103"
    },
    "ShipAddr": {
      "Id": "9",
      "Line1": "100 Street",
      "City": "Bangalore",
      "Country": "India",
      "CountrySubDivisionCode": "Karnataka",
      "PostalCode": "560103"
    },
    "Job": false,
    "BillWithParent": false,
    "Balance": 0,
    "BalanceWithJobs": 0,
    "PreferredDeliveryMethod": "Email",
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "16",
    "SyncToken": "0",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2014-09-22T21:54:13-07:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-09-22T21:54:13-07:00"
    },
    "GivenName": "AA",
    "FullyQualifiedName": "AA",
    "DisplayName": "AA",
    "PrintOnCheckName": "AA",
    "Active": true
  },
  "time": "2014-09-22T21:55:17.28-07:00"
}
```

---

Update Request

```
{
    "Taxable": false,
    "BillAddr": {
      "Id": "9",
      "Line1": "100 Street",
      "City": "Bangalore",
      "Country": "India",
      "CountrySubDivisionCode": "Karnataka",
      "PostalCode": "560103"
    },
    "Job": false,
    "BillWithParent": false,
    "Balance": 0,
    "BalanceWithJobs": 0,
    "PreferredDeliveryMethod": "Email",
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "16",
    "SyncToken": "0",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2014-09-22T21:54:13-07:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-09-22T21:54:13-07:00"
    },
    "GivenName": "AA",
    "FullyQualifiedName": "AA",
    "DisplayName": "AA",
    "PrintOnCheckName": "AA",
    "Active": true
}
```

### Get By Id

```
{
  "Customer": {
    "Taxable": false,
    "BillAddr": {
      "Id": "9",
      "Line1": "100 Street",
      "City": "Bangalore",
      "Country": "India",
      "CountrySubDivisionCode": "Karnataka",
      "PostalCode": "560103"
    },
    "Job": false,
    "BillWithParent": false,
    "Balance": 0,
    "BalanceWithJobs": 0,
    "PreferredDeliveryMethod": "Email",
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "16",
    "SyncToken": "1",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2014-09-22T21:54:13-07:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-09-22T21:56:21-07:00"
    },
    "GivenName": "AA",
    "FullyQualifiedName": "AA",
    "DisplayName": "AA",
    "PrintOnCheckName": "AA",
    "Active": true
  },
  "time": "2014-09-22T21:56:49.814-07:00"
}
```

Did you try XML payload. It worked fine for me. PFB below request/response.
I'll verify the JSON way and update this post.

```
<Customer xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" domain="QBO" sparse="false">
            <Id>14</Id>
            <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
            <MetaData>
                <CreateTime>2014-09-22T21:04:02-07:00</CreateTime>
                <LastUpdatedTime>2014-09-22T21:04:02-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
            </MetaData>
            <GivenName>Neo</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Light</FamilyName>
            <FullyQualifiedName>Neo Light</FullyQualifiedName>
            <CompanyName>ABC</CompanyName>
            <DisplayName>Neo Light</DisplayName>
            <PrintOnCheckName>Neo Light</PrintOnCheckName>
            <Active>true</Active>
            <PrimaryEmailAddr>
                <Address>abc@abc.co.in</Address>
            </PrimaryEmailAddr>
            <Taxable>false</Taxable>
            <BillAddr>
                <Id>7</Id>
                <Line1>ABC Street</Line1>
                <City>Bangalore</City>
                <Country>India</Country>
                <CountrySubDivisionCode>Karnataka</CountrySubDivisionCode>
                <PostalCode>560103</PostalCode>
            </BillAddr>
            <ShipAddr>
                <Id>7</Id>
                <Line1>ABC Street</Line1>
                <City>Bangalore</City>
                <Country>India</Country>
                <CountrySubDivisionCode>Karnataka</CountrySubDivisionCode>
                <PostalCode>560103</PostalCode>
            </ShipAddr>
            <Job>false</Job>
            <BillWithParent>false</BillWithParent>
            <Balance>0</Balance>
            <BalanceWithJobs>0</BalanceWithJobs>
            <PreferredDeliveryMethod>Email</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
        </Customer>
```

**Update request**

```
<Customer xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" domain="QBO" sparse="false">
    <Id>14</Id>
    <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2014-09-22T21:04:02-07:00</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2014-09-22T21:04:02-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <GivenName>Neo</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>Light</FamilyName>
    <FullyQualifiedName>Neo Light</FullyQualifiedName>
    <CompanyName>ABC</CompanyName>
    <DisplayName>Neo Light</DisplayName>
    <PrintOnCheckName>Neo Light1</PrintOnCheckName>
    <Active>true</Active>
    <PrimaryEmailAddr>
        <Address>abc@abc.co.in</Address>
    </PrimaryEmailAddr>
    <Taxable>false</Taxable>
    <BillAddr>
        <Id>7</Id>
        <Line1>ABC Street</Line1>
        <City>Bangalore</City>
        <Country>India</Country>
        <CountrySubDivisionCode>Karnataka</CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <PostalCode>560103</PostalCode>
    </BillAddr>
    <Job>false</Job>
    <BillWithParent>false</BillWithParent>
    <Balance>0</Balance>
    <BalanceWithJobs>0</BalanceWithJobs>
    <PreferredDeliveryMethod>Email</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
</Customer>
```

**Verified that 'shipAddr' is not present anymore**

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-09-22T21:07:31.919-07:00">
  <Customer domain="QBO" sparse="false">
    <Id>14</Id>
    <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
      <CreateTime>2014-09-22T21:04:02-07:00</CreateTime>
      <LastUpdatedTime>2014-09-22T21:06:58-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <GivenName>Neo</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>Light</FamilyName>
    <FullyQualifiedName>Neo Light</FullyQualifiedName>
    <CompanyName>ABC</CompanyName>
    <DisplayName>Neo Light</DisplayName>
    <PrintOnCheckName>Neo Light1</PrintOnCheckName>
    <Active>true</Active>
    <PrimaryEmailAddr>
      <Address>abc@abc.co.in</Address>
    </PrimaryEmailAddr>
    <Taxable>false</Taxable>
    <BillAddr>
      <Id>7</Id>
      <Line1>ABC Street</Line1>
      <City>Bangalore</City>
      <Country>India</Country>
      <CountrySubDivisionCode>Karnataka</CountrySubDivisionCode>
      <PostalCode>560103</PostalCode>
    </BillAddr>
    <Job>false</Job>
    <BillWithParent>false</BillWithParent>
    <Balance>0</Balance>
    <BalanceWithJobs>0</BalanceWithJobs>
    <PreferredDeliveryMethod>Email</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
  </Customer>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried this exact example (the json one) in the API Explorer and it does NOT work. I created the object in my own company using your first json blob, then I took the response body and just deleted the shipping address sub-dict and pasted it into the update request body. The response body for the update request still has a shipping address. I'll try the xml payload too.

Comment: Didn't work in the API Explorer using the exact xml request bodies you provide above either. What else can we try?

Comment: I had tried this from ApiExplorer only. Please raise a support ticket mentioning the relamId. Thanks

Comment: It seems you cannot remove this data using sparse update...